# MVC AttributeRouting Precedence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I am having a bit of an issue with precendence. I've read through the documentation, but I have been unable to solve the problem.

I have the following site, "mysite.com". Within the site I have the route

> [GET("{type}")]

That route lets me say "mysite.com/art", or "mysite.com/theatre".

My problem then, is that when I try to create a route for "mysite.com/venues", with the route

> [GET("venues")]

It always tries to put "venues" as the parameter within the "Type" action.

I have tried adding

> [GET("{type}"), ControllerPrecedence = -1]

... with no luck. I've also tried amending the RouteConfig with:

> routes.MapRoute(
>                   name: "venues",
>                   url: "venues",
>                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Venues" }
>               );

... also with no luck. Lastly, I tried:

> routes.MapAttributeRoutes(config =>
>               {
>                   config.AddRoutesFromController();
>                   config.AddRoutesFromController();
>                   config.UseLowercaseRoutes = true;
>               });

After splitting the actions out into a new controller, but again, nothing helped.

The only thing I can think to do is to change the route to be:

> [GET("p/venues")]

... but that isn't the nicest of URLs.

Do you have any suggestions of what else I can try?

Thanks a load.

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The route that I had mainly tested with took a parameter, but I'd missed making the parameter optional, so although it would have been hitting the route, because there was no parameter it went to the next in line.